# $\int_0^1f(x)dx=1, \int_0^1xf(x)dx=\frac16$ minimum value of $\int_0^1f^2(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f(x)\geq0$ be a Riemann integrable function, and

$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=1, \int_0^1xf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac16.$$

Find the minimum value of  $\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx$

---

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?  en, I'm  in trouble for $f(x)\geq0$

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We equip the space of Riemann square integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with the usual scalar product. Now we have
$$
\int_0^1(1-2x)f(x)dx=1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{2}{3}=\int_0^{1/2}(1-2x)f(x)dx+\underbrace{\int_{1/2}^1(1-2x)f(x)dx}_{\leq 0}
$$
it follows that, if $g(x)=4(1-2x){\bf 1}_{[0,1/2]}$ then
$$
\frac{8}{3}\leq\int_0^{1}4(1-2x){\bf 1}_{[0,1/2]}f(x)dx=\langle f,g\rangle\tag{1}
$$
On the other hand we have 
$$\eqalign{
\Vert g\Vert^2&=16\int_0^{1/2}(1-2x)^2dx=\frac{8}{3}\leq\langle f,g\rangle\cr}
$$
So $\langle f-g,g\rangle\geq0$, hence
$$
\Vert f\Vert^2=\Vert f-g\Vert^2+\Vert g\Vert^2+2\langle f-g,g\rangle\geq
\Vert f-g\Vert^2+\Vert g\Vert^2\tag{2}
$$
But $g$ is positive and satisfies
$$\langle g,1\rangle =4\int_0^{1/2}(1-2x) dx=1,\quad
\langle g,x\rangle =4\int_0^{1/2}x(1-2x) dx=\frac{1}{6}
$$
So, from $(2)$ we conclude that $\Vert f\Vert^2\geq\Vert g\Vert^2$ with equality, if and only if $f=g$, and the desired minimum is $\Vert g\Vert^2=8/3$.

**Acknowledgment** I want to acknowledge here that this solution, came from  [Vladimir](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154757/vladimir)'s observation, presented in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f$ provide the desired minimum. If $g$ is continuous, supported in $\{x:f(x)>0\}$, and satisfies $\int g dx=\int xg dx=0$, then $f+tg$ satisfies the constraints for small $t$ and we have $\int (f+tg)^2dx\ge\int f^2 dx$ for any $t$ $\implies$ $\int fg dx=0$.  This holds for every continuous $g$ satisfying $\int g dx=\int xg dx=0$ and supported in $\{x:f(x)>0\}$, and hence there exist constants $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=a+bx$ on the set $K=\{x:f(x)>0\}$. If we could somehow prove that, for optimal $f$, $K$ has to be an interval of the form $[0,x_0)$, then the answer probably is $f(x)=4-8x$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$ and $0$ afterwards.

Comment: +1. Still assuming continuity (which is not given). If $f\neq 0$ at some point then it is locally linear there  (by a variational argument).  Then $f$ is V-shaped on $[0,1]$ with a root at the tip. A tedious computation shows that $4-8x$ indeed gives the minimum square norm under the given constraints.

Comment: Yes, indeed, $4-8x$ rather than $8-4x$. Sorry for the misprint.

Comment: Well, to be completely pedantic, my argument shows that $f(x)=a+bx$ on each set $K_\epsilon=\{f(x)>\epsilon\}$ for $\epsilon>0$ and hence on $K=\bigcup_{\epsilon>0}K_\epsilon$. Continuity is neither used nor follows from this.

Comment: I also used a similar approach, but the real problem was to prove (1) the existence of a minimizing function and (2) the continuity of minimizers (or some property that is comparable to this property). Indeed, in your argument it was essential that we can pick a plethora of continuous function on $\{ x : f(x) > 0 \}$ for the variational argument to work, though this needs justification. (There is even no guarantee that this set has non-empty interior!) And I think that justifying this variational argument is the most technically daunting part of the proof. Oh, and of course +1 vote.

Comment: Yes you are right of course. If the interior of $K_\varepsilon$ happens to be empty, we are in trouble.

Comment: But not in so much trouble, because we can take arbitrary Lebesgue integrable $g$ a.e. uniformly bounded and vanishing outside $K_\epsilon$. Thus, we can still prove that if the minimizer $f$ exists at all, then $f=a+bx$ on the (measurable) set where $f>0$.

Comment: Existence of the unique $L^{2}$-minimizer is easy to prove: it is a direct consequence of Hilbert space theory. Indeed, the set $$ E = \{f \in L^{2}[0, 1] : \textstyle \int_{0}^{1} f = 1, \textstyle \int_{0}^{1} xf = 1/6, f \geq 0 \} $$ is closed and convex, hence contains a unique distance-minimizer.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. But still I am not sure how we, having proved that the $L_2$-minimizer is of this form, prove that the set $K$ is actually an interval.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am also struggling with that. :(